# How to jump to a specific ride over the deep link API

Tags: uber-api

is there a way to jump directly to a specific ride over the Uber deep link API? With the setPickup action I can directly request a new ride. Is there an action like 'showPickup' which would open the Uber app and jump directly to a specific ride? 
Thanks for a reply
Jean-Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to go to a specific ride id. That said, it shouldn't ever be needed as Uber only support a single ride per rider at any given time so if you open the app while the user is on-trip it will always open to the existing ride.

Comment: Ok thany you Dustin for the reply. I am new to Uber so I did not know that it supports only a single ride, in that case you are right we can just open the app with the uber:// deep link without specifying a specific ride.